# Check Bluetooth status in Xamarin Forms on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, bluetooth

I have created a xamarin forms application. I want to check if the status of the bluetooth in iOS. I have used the below code, but the `if (state == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn)` is returning me `Unknown`. It is not providing the actual status of bluetooth state. Could somebody please help me to figure out what is wrong ? Thanks.

The reference of this method is here : https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoMac.CoreBluetooth.CBCentralManagerState/

```
   private CBCentralManagerState state;

    public bool CheckBluetoothStatus()
    {
        bool status;
        if (state == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn)
        {
            status=  true;
        }
        else
        {
            status =  false;
        }
        return status;   

    }
```

Comment: What's your device? What's the OS version? Did you create the CBCentralManager object? Also, wait until https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/MonoMac.CoreBluetooth.CBCentralManagerDelegate.UpdatedState/p/MonoMac.CoreBluetooth.CBCentralManager/ is called to check it.

Comment: @Larme Its an iphone 6s.

Comment: Did you create the CBCentralManager object?

Comment: Yes I have created it as private CBCentralManagerState state;`

Comment: @Larme could you help ?

Answer (score 4):

As described here in [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanager), you need to initialise CBCentralManager before you can actually use it.

If you look at [Xamarin Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.CoreBluetooth.CBCentralManager/) for CBCentralManager, they provide you a list of all constructors it takes. Implement the 2nd one from the bottom

```
CBCentralManager(CBCentralManagerDelegate, DispatchQueue, CBCentralInitOptions)
```

But before you implement this, you need to implement the CBCentralManagerDelegate. It could be as simple as this

```
public class CbCentralDelegate : CBCentralManagerDelegate
{
    public override void UpdatedState(CBCentralManager central)
    {
        if(central.State == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Powered On");
        }
    }
}
```

Now that you have implemented the delegate, you should be able to fetch the state of the bluetooth from the CBCentralManager like this

```
var bluetoothManager = new CBCentralManager(new CbCentralDelegate(),DispatchQueue.DefaultGlobalQueue,
                                                        new CBCentralInitOptions{ShowPowerAlert = true});

return bluetoothManager.State == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn;
```

I know its been a while since this was asked, but hopefully this will help you.(Or anyone else)

Comment: does this require any permissions to be set?

Comment: @NitinS no bluetooth doesnt require explicit permissions for iOS 12 and prior versions. From iOS 13 permissions are needed https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/handling-ios-13-bluetooth-permissions-26c6a8cbb816

Answer (score 0):

You should subscript the UpdatedState event in CBCentralManager

```
_mgr = new CBCentralManager();
_mgr.UpdatedState += CBCentralManager_UpdatedState;
void CBCentralManager_UpdatedState(object sender, EventArgs e){
    switch (_mgr.State)
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a more detailed example please ?